# Unable to retrieve a file when using a parameter

Tags: java, android

I am having an issue when it comes to passing a parameter to search for a file. 
Basically when trying to read a file, this code worked:

```
private void setContent(){
        String text = "";
        String randomText = "";

try
{

InputStream input = getAssets().open("files/jokes.txt");

            int size = input.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();
            // byte buffer into a string
            text = new String(buffer);

            String[] splitText = text.split("###");
            Random rand = new Random();
            int  randomIndex = rand.nextInt(splitText.length);
            randomText = splitText[randomIndex];

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        contentText.setText(randomText);

    }
```

Notice the InputStream above. My text file is stored in asssets/files/jokes.txt.

Now that I try and use an intent a parmatised the file name as so, it always hits the catch statement with the filename being caught as "" when it goes past:

**Main Activity:**

```
jokesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openContentPage("jokes");
        }
    });

    poemsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openContentPage("poems");
        }
    });

    funnyStoriesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openContentPage("funnyStories");
        }
    });
```

...

```
  private void openContentPage(String v) {
        if (v.equals("jokes")) {
            Intent intentContentPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Content.class);
            intentContentPage.putExtra("keyPage", "jokes");
            startActivity(intentContentPage);
        } else if (v.equals("poems")) {
            Intent intentContentPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Content.class);
            intentContentPage.putExtra("keyPage", "poems");
            startActivity(intentContentPage);
        } else if (v.equals("funnyStories")) {
            Intent intentContentPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Content.class);
            intentContentPage.putExtra("keyPage", "funnyStories");
            startActivity(intentContentPage);
        }
```

**Content:**

```
 private void setContent(){
        String text = "";
        String randomText = "";
        String keyPageValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("keyPage");

        String fileName = "";

        if(keyPageValue.equals("jokes") ){
            fileName.equals("files/jokes.txt");
        }
        else if (keyPageValue.equals("poems")){
            fileName.equals("files/poems.txt");
        }
        else if (keyPageValue.equals("funnyStories")){
            fileName.equals("files/funnystories.txt");
        }

        try {

            InputStream input = getAssets().open(fileName);

            int size = input.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();
            // byte buffer into a string
            text = new String(buffer);

            String[] splitText = text.split("###");
            Random rand = new Random();
            int  randomIndex = rand.nextInt(splitText.length);
            randomText = splitText[randomIndex];

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        contentText.setText(randomText);

    }
```

How come it does not select it? All files are stored in the assets/files folder as previously mentioned.

Comment: `String fileName = "";` That should be `String fileName = "files/" + keyPageValue;`. Thats all. Remove all .equals().

Comment: `if (v.equals("jokes")) {
            Intent intentContentPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Content.class);
            intentContentPage.putExtra("keyPage", "jokes");
            startActivity(intentContentPage);`. You have three of those blocks.

Comment: That is not needed. You only need `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Content.class);
            intent.putExtra("keyPage", v);
            startActivity(intent);`.

Comment: Thanks guys, fixed it

Comment: You have problems with counting?

Comment: no problems with counting

Comment: ??? How many guys did you see?